# Spring Aspect - How to identify which Pointcut triggers the function

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-aspects

I want to log Controller and the rest of packages differently. I know I can use 2 separate methods for this but these 2 methods are very similar, so I want to add a code to check that would look something like this

```
@Around("controllerPoint() || theRest()")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  if( called from controllerPoint() ) {
      execute this short section of code                     # (1)            
  }
// rest of code
```

What would this code be like?

Also, if after I execute (1) and I want to pass a variable to this same method again when it executes for other packages, how can I do it?

Comment: Don't... Just write the 2 methods and extract the shared stuff into a method that you call from both. That will be much easier to reason about that trying to shoehorn all of it into a single method.

Answer (score 0):

you can invoke the method like the below which will return your method name

```
joinPoint.getSignature().getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get method name, from join point:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class TrackingConfig {

    @Around("execution(* your.package.Controller.*(..))")
    public Object doConcurrentOperation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        if ("theRest".equals(methodName)) {
            System.out.println("AROUND! theRest ");
        } else if ("controllerPoint".equals(methodName)) {
            System.out.println("AROUND! controllerPoint ");
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```